# Why does !! inside an alias not work?

Tags: bash, alias, command-history, history-expansion

I have this alias set in my system `/etc/bashrc` file:

```
alias root="sudo !!"
```

The intention of this being to run the last used command using `sudo` of course. When used, it of course appears to substitute the last command in `history` to the `bashrc` file upon shell initialization, and not the actual command that you would get if you were to run `sudo !!` in an interactive shell. I've also tried `alias root="sudo fc -s"` to no avail.

I realize this is probably something to do with how the BASH does command substitutions, but can someone explain why this is, and provide a usable substitute?

I'm running BASH version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13).

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I use GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) and ls;sudo !! works well!

Comment: (x86_64-apple-darwin13) - Mac Os X :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, when in an alias. I do not believe Sepahrad tried this as an alias, if you try `ls; sudo !!` that will work by itself in a shell.

Comment: worksforme in an interactive shell without sudo. Even the help for `fc` suggests an alias, so this is more likely to be a problem of switching users/shells.

Comment: @slm, Yes I didn't test it as alias... It's doesn't work for me too! +1 to Question.

Comment: Yeah the issue here is that you cannot pass arguments such as this to an alias. Think of aliases as macros that get expanded. So it's impossible to pass `!!` to an alias, and have the alias expand it later.

Comment: When using double quotes, the `!!` is actually expanded when defining the alias, so the alias will sudo-execute the command last used before the definition instead of the command used before calling the alias.

Answer (score 11):

The key part in this behavior is explained by 2 bits in the bash manpage:

In the `HISTORY EXPANSION` section:

> History  expansion  is  performed immediately after a complete line is read, before the shell breaks it into words.

In the `ALIASES` section:

> The first word of each simple command, if unquoted, is checked to  see  if it has an alias.

So basically history expansion occurs before word splitting. Alias expansion occurs after.

---

#### Alternate solution

The best way I can think of doing this is the following:

```
alias root='sudo $(fc -ln -1)'
```

This will work for simple commands, but for more complex ones we need to tweak it.

```
alias root='sudo sh -c "$(fc -ln -1)"'
```

The reason for the change is because of something like this:

```
# alias root='sudo $(fc -ln -1)'
# echo "I AM $(whoami)"
I AM patrick
# root
"I AM $(whoami)"
```

As you can see no shell parsing is done. By changing it to use `sh -c "..."` instead, it does shell interpretation.

```
# alias root='sudo sh -c "$(fc -ln -1)"'
# echo "I AM $(whoami)"
I AM patrick
# root
I AM root
```

Another way (I thought of this one first, so keeping it in the answer, but it's not as nice as the one above):

```
alias root='fc -e "sed -i -e \"s/^/sudo /\""'
```

The `fc -e` command will run the specified command passing it a file containing the previously executed command. We just run `sed` on that file to prefix the command with `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks, never even noticed the `fc` command before.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I never heard `fc` command before.

Comment: So, in that case, why does `alias root="sudo fc -s"` not work then?

Comment: @slm `fc` is really neat for a range of commands more than a single one (at least to me).

Comment: @xanadu because 1) it's a shell builtin, not a normal command 2) it uses the history of the current shell. Once you use sudo, you don't necessarily get a shell, and if you do, it's a new shell with new history.

Comment: `alias root='sudo sh -c "$(fc -ln -1)"'` doesn't recognize alias. For example, if I try `S neofetch` where `S` is alias for `pacman -S` first. Then run `root`, it will prompt `sh: S: command not found` even if I define `alias S='pacman -S'` in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: To save my day, I use `alias S='sudo pacman -S'` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an alias in this way. Aliases cannot be passed parameters such as `!!`. To achieve what you want you could use a function instead.

```
function root() {
  sudo $(history | tail -2 | head -1 | awk '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}');
}
```

This is a rough idea though and may have some problems. My output from the history command looks like this:

```
$ history
1081  20131205 08:00:12  ls
1082  20131205 08:00:13  history
```

So I need to parse this output. In the above I'm running history taking the last 2 commands, then taking the first of the last 2 This is the previously run command. I then use `awk` to get rid of the first 4 columns, leaving us with the command line that was previously run.

#### As an alias?

Given we're using the output from `history`, there's really no longer any reason to use a Bash function. This is needed if you're attempting to pass the previous command in as an argument, but we're getting it via the `history` command now.

```
$ alias root="sudo \$(history | tail -2 | head -1 | awk '{\$1=\$2=\$3=\"\"; print \$0}')"
```

Beyond the trickier escaping required to get this into an alias, the above works, similar to the function.

Comment: There are no parameters here, so an alias would be fine. It's what you put in the command substitution that matters.

Comment: @Gilles - are you saying what I've created could've been put into an alias as well?

Comment: Yes (with careful quoting). It's more complex than I would put in an alias, and doesn't usefully take arguments at the end unlike an alias, but it could be an alias.

Comment: Of course that a `!!` could be an alias or an alias parameter (just  deactivate History). Example: Try: `set +H; alias r='echo !!'; r`.